# Restart an external process from within a nodejs app (linux)

Tags: node.js, process, child-process, pm2, restart

Say that I am running a process from the command line (NOT a nodejs app):

```
myProcess doSomething --withParam1
```

I am also running a nodejs app that connects to this process (rpc).

```
node myApp
```

`myProcess` will randomly silently fail to work properly without crashing and `myApp` will detect it. I need `myApp` to be able to restart `myProcess` (kill it and start it again). After I restarted `myProcess`, `myApp` will also restart itself using pm2 (I am already handling the pm2 restart part for the nodejs app - my issue is that I cannot use pm2 to restart `myProcess` since it is not a nodejs app). Also, I cannot change the code of `myProcess` since it is a 3rd party software.

How can I restart the external process from my nodejs app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [process.kill](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processkillpid-signal) to kill the process and nodejs [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to restart it.

To find the pid of the process before killing it, I used this:

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');

function printPid() {
    childProcess.exec('pidof -s myProcess', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    });
}
```